# Profanity filter

Tags: java

So far I have been able to censor "cat", "dog" and "llama". Now I just need to make the exception of "Dogmatic" but cannot figure it out for the life of me. Below I have attached what I have so far. Please any suggestions will help really.

```
/* take userinput and determine if it contains profanity
 * if userinput contains profanity, it will be filtered 
 * and a new sentence will be generated with the word censored
 */
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Welcome to the Star Bulletin Board!");
System.out.println("Generate your first post below!");

String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

if (userInput.indexOf("cat") != 15){
    System.out.println("Your post contains profanity.");
    System.out.println("I have altered your post to appear as: ");
    System.out.println(userInput.replaceAll("cat", "***"));
}
else 
    System.out.println(userInput);

if (userInput.indexOf("dog") != -1){
    System.out.println("Your post contains profanity.");
    System.out.println("I have altered your post to appear as: ");
    System.out.println(userInput.replaceAll("dog", "***"));
}
if (userInput.indexOf("llama")!= -1){
    System.out.println("Your post contains profanity.");
    System.out.println("I have altered your post to appear as: ");
    System.out.println(userInput.replaceAll("llama", "*****"));
}
```

Comment: Check for spaces so only individual words are picked out. Probably easier with a regex.

Comment: Can you show me an example of this? I'm still fairly new to java and programming as a whole

Comment: You should probably split on a set of delimiters, so people can't go round calling each other "you_big_llama!" or substituting space for the alt+255 character. (Fun fact: `Command and Conquer: Generals` profanity censor fails to do this)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a word boundary `\\b`. Word boundaries match the edges of a word, like spaces or punctuation.

```
if (userInput.matches(".*\\bdog\\b.*")) {
    userInput = userInput.replaceAll("\\bdog\\b", "***");
}
```

This will censor *"Don't be a llama."* but it won't censor *"Don't be dogmatic."*

`userInput.matches(".*\\bdog\\b.*")` is a slightly better condition than `indexOf`/`contains` because it has the same match as the replacement. `indexOf`/`contains` would still show the message despite not censoring anything. `.*` matches any character (except typically new lines), optionally.

Note: this is still not a very effective way to filter profanity. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. What would be a more effective way of filtering? Just so I can have this under my belt.

Comment: Real people is the only effective profanity filter. Read Jeff's post. Otherwise you can pick one side to err on. You either erroneously censor stuff like *dogmatic* or check for something like word boundaries which makes the filter easy to get around.

Comment: @RyanLenig, Yes, you could use fuzzy text matching, bayesian classification, arrays of all the permutations of words you want filtered, and a million other methods. But real people would be the best way.

Comment: And real people means: basically every social application should have some kind of "report"/"flag"/"vote to kick" feature for users who are abusive or have found a way to circumvent a filter.

Answer (score 2):

Use word boundaries. Take a look at the following code; it will print `true` for all cases except the last one:

```
String a = "what you there";
String b = "yes what there";
String c = "yes there what";
String d = "whatabout this";

System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\bwhat\\b").matcher(a).find());
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\bwhat\\b").matcher(b).find());
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\bwhat\\b").matcher(c).find());
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\bwhat\\b").matcher(d).find());
```

You can combine all your bad words into a single regex like so:

```
Pattern filter = Pattern.compile("\\b(cat|llama|dog)\\b");
```

This is fine for simple cases, but for a more robust solution you probably want to use a library. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521646/what-s-the-best-profanity-filter-which-supports-java-integration) for more information.